# Need to (force) the refresh of the MS Access database immediately after the delete statement

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I use an MS Access database. In the code below, I loop through a recordset and delete each record. Directly after the delete statement, the function RefreshPlanning perform a select query based on the same table. The problem is that the record is not instantly deleted in the table and so the RefreshPlanning is querying some record who normally has been deleted! So I need to refresh the db (empty the cache?) instantly after the delete statement. How can I proceed?

```
    Dim rstTraitements as ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstTraitements = SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM tblTraitements WHERE ID like 123")

    ' Loop through all selected elements.
    While Not rstTraitements.EOF
       ' Delete current record in the table.
       rstTraitements.Delete
       MsgBox "a database refresh is needed here before the next statement"
       RefreshPlanning DatePlanning, CodeEquipement           
       rstTraitements.MoveNext
    Wend
```

Remark 1: SelectQuery is a function who return a recordset

Remark 2: RefreshPlanning is a function who perform a select query based on the same table (tblTraitements).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you doing all of these operations against one Connection?

Comment: Opening a recordset to delete each row is inefficient.  Could it work to substitute `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblTraitements WHERE ID = 123"`, then run your RefreshPlanning function once after the rows have been deleted?

Comment: @HansUp--Very true, but if you're opening the Recordset anyway, for further processing, you might as well do the delete there.

Comment: If using the same recordset for both purposes causes this problem, then it seems to me that it's inadvisable to do things this way. I just don't see any reason to do deletes by walking a recordset. I suspect that this code could be re-architected easily to get rid of both problems, but since we don't know what `RefreshPlanning DatePlanning, CodeEquipement` does, it's impossible to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Bob: Yes only one Connection. But this problem is solved using a requery on the recordset. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @HansUp: I agree with you but I cannot perform a "DELETE * ..." in my case. I didn't publish all my code in this post. I resume this for clarity. I need to loop through each record to perform some actions on each and only after that I can delete the record and proceed with the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
rstTraitements.Resync
```

or

```
rstTraitements.Requery
```

after the delete

Comment: It works with the Requery. One drawback is that I need to replace the statement **rstTraitements.MoveNext** by **If Not rstTraitements.EOF then rstTraitementrs.MoveFirst** otherwise one record is missing. What do you think?

Comment: That should be fine.  Alternatively, you can probably change the loop to `Do While True`, replace the MoveNext with `If rstTraitements.EOF Then Exit Do` and replace `Wend` with `Loop`

Comment: `Requery` actually runs the whole SELECT statement again. Looks like serious performance penalty. Did you try calling `Update` (after the `Delete`) on the recordset?